# For graduate school applications, is it worth retaking classes with poor performance or just focusing on future class marks?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, gpa

So, I am a physics student at UC Berkeley. However, at one point, just due to its utility and my own passion for the subject, I wanted to double major in math. Around a year ago, I had very bad personal circumstances which led to notably poor marks in two of the three courses I took that semester, namely two C+ marks. One of these was in an upper division math course, which, today I feel good about in terms of how I understand it, given that I use it almost daily. Due to this fact, I wonder if I should retake this course for the sake of graduate school applications. This question also extends to other courses I haven’t performed that well in.

As of now, my cumulative GPA is a 3.0 (have been receiving B- or B in most technical courses, unfortunately), which almost says no to any graduate school (especially because at the moment, research experience simply is not enough to compensate). This is largely a result of the fact that I have immense exam stress, rather than the fact that I don’t understand my courses, but of course graduate schools would not care about this or see this just by seeing my GPA. I have calculated that if I were to receive the A mark in the remainder of my courses up until graduation, I could end with a 3.7. However, that could be higher if a retook a course or two, one of which is that upper division math course. But would graduate admission officers really consider a low mark in a course that isn’t directly in my field of study, is something I’ve wondered.

I know GPA is not all that matters in these applications, but as I understand it, it is a big deal. In any case, I plan to take the GRE (at least in my subject).

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to [this](https://registrar.berkeley.edu/academic-records/grades/#:~:text=Students%20may%20repeat%20a%20course,pass%20(NP%20or%20U).&text=After%20repeating%20a%20course%2C%20both,be%20calculated%20into%20your%20GPA.) you can only retake courses if you receive a D+ or lower.

Comment: Somehow, I believe that that must be the guidelines for when someone must take a course, given that I know some people that have retaken courses. But, I will keep this in mind and ask an advisor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every case is different, but it would probably be time better spent if you focus on doing well in the future, especially in courses in the major. A single C+ grad isn't going to derail you. Your in-major GPA will be more important than any particular grade.

Admissions committees don't expect perfection, but they do expect evidence of future success.

For your exam phobias, the university probably has an office that can help with that: a "study center" or counseling office, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Luk'yan,

This is not an exact answer to your question, but sooner some additional food for thought. While at some departments the selection of graduate students is a very formal process run by the admissions committee, at other places things are less formal, and what matters more is the desire of one or another faculty to take you as his or her PhD student. Whether this will overweigh a low GPA -- that may vary wildly from one department to another.

Another factor to consider is whether you are aiming at a career in theoretical or experimental physics. Suppose, very hypothetically, that some faculty informs the admissions committee that (s)he wants to take you.  The committee may then look up for what courses you failed to get a high grade.  If you are to join an experimentalist group, then a low grade in a purely mathematical course will be less detrimental.  But then, again, it all depends on the style and tradition at a particular department, and on how strongly some faculty advocates your case.

In what area, approximately, are you planning to specialise in grad school?

Comment: I actually really like theory more than experiment, but both I am okay with. My current interests are in experimental AMO (atomic, molecular, and optical) physics, and condensed matter theory.